# multidimensional function for object description

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mathematics

I want to simulate a bow tie antenna and build it up with a function. so far i have managed to create a piece of cake with sin and cos.

Now I would like to expand the function and round off the corners, but I don't know how to do it mathematically. does anyone know how to create such a function?

I have attached a picture of the current state.
[image]